# Cookies going through moovweb project have their domains overwritten to "."

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I have a project using the mixer "simple-mobile (1.0.183)".  I a request returns a response with the Set-Cookie header, those cookies have the domain set to just "."

Here's an example response header from a curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: nginx 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
Content-Length: 23 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727 
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=xu1qyg45ghzqveeuwa1ix1aa; path=/; HttpOnly; domain=. 
Set-Cookie: ec_session=511840684.20480.0000; path=/; domain=. 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Connection: keep-alive
```

As you can see, the domain section of the cookie is set to just "."  I'm not really messing with cookies anywhere in my tritium, and I don't use any of the cookie helper functions.  I've had other moovweb projects set the domain correctly (in this case, it would be ".example.com").

Anyone know what might be going on with my cookies?